# Principal does not contain a definition for 'EmailAddress'

Tags: c#, windows-services, directoryservices

I'm trying to retrieve users from an OU on a Windows 2016 Service via a Windows Service App (to synchronise accounts to another service).

I've got the code below to search the OU and then add the results to a list.

```
List<string> UserList = new List<string>();

PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain, OU);
UserPrincipal userqbe = new UserPrincipal(context);
PrincipalSearcher searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(userqbe);

foreach (var found in searcher.FindAll())
{
    UserList.Add(found.EmailAddress);
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

> 'Principal' does not contain a definition for 'EmailAddress' [...] (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)

After that error I've referenced the assemblies required:

- `System.DirectoryServices`
- `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagent`

And included them in my code:

```
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
```

---

The [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) about the user principle class does show an `EmailAddress` property. Other properties like `DisplayName` do work correctly.

What am I missing here?

Comment: `foreach (var found in searcher.FindAll().OfType<UserPrincipal>())`?

Comment: Spelling matters.  "Principal" != "principle".  And the `EmailAddress` property has two Ds while your question title `EmailAdress` is missing one.

Comment: So either your problem is "typos" or you didn't show the actual error message.

Comment: @stuartd that resolved the issue, add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `FindAll` documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalsearcher.findall?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_DirectoryServices_AccountManagement_PrincipalSearcher_FindAll

Returns

```
PrincipalSearchResult<Principal>
```

So,  just cast your found object

```
UserList.Add(((UserPrincipal)found).EmailAddress);
```

Mind you, this is dangerous if you are not sure about the principal type. To avoid any runtime errors you can use the Is operator https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is